# WPF label like ItemsControl/Selector

Tags: .net, wpf

In WPF, how to build a label like ItemsControl/Selector? I need a control looks like a label but can feed a collection of data from ItemsSource property and diplay the text according to DisplayMemberPath property. The user cannot change the value. It is just for display only.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an ItemsControl using a StackPanel as its ItemsPanel, something like this:

Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:TestViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText}" Margin=5/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Or if you want to use the DisplayMemberPath you could have

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:TestViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="ItemText">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

View model

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<TestItem>
                    {
                        new TestItem{ItemText = "One"},
                        new TestItem{ItemText = "Two"},
                        new TestItem{ItemText = "Three"},
                    };
    }
    public IEnumerable<TestItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class TestItem
{
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
}
```

A simple (slightly hacky) solution for displaying a single selected item of text is to style a list box

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:TestViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <TextBlock Text=
                                   "{Binding RelativeSource=
                                     {RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, 
                                     Path=SelectedItem.ItemText}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="2" />
</Grid>
```

A better solution would be to create a custom control based on a Selector, and make the control templatable.

Comment: What if I need to display only SelectedItem? Like a combo box but appear as a textblock